# How do i get multiple outputs from 1 loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this to show me the incremental increases for each time hori_dist is being calculated. Instead it is just showing me the final result all added up together. How do i get it to output 5 values since my range is 5?

Googled for videos, searched online, tried this multiple ways

```
Vx0 = 18
Vy0 = 18
V = 18
Theta = 45
y0 = 1.8    
x0 = 0
p = 1.2#given density
C = 0.3#Drag coefficient
dt = 0.2#Time increment

def x_direction (x0, Vx0, dt):
"""Calculate the distance moved in x axis"""
new_dist = 0
for hori_dist in range(5):
   hori_dist = x0 + Vx0*dt
   new_dist = new_dist + hori_dist
return new_dist

new_dist = x_direction(x0, Vx0, dt)
print ("Distanced moved in x direction is :", new_dist)
```

Comment: Put the `print` statement inside the loop, if you want to print during each iteration through the loop.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  As shown, we can't tell what code is part of the function, and what code is part of the for loop inside the function.

Comment: use `new_dist += hori_dist`. Also in the future, throw out unnecessary lines, e.g. lines 2-5, 7, 8. Maybe answer to your question lies in [yield](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+yield) statement, go check it out

Answer (score 1):

To define a *scope*, many languages use the curly braces *{ }*. Python, however, uses indentation.

So, if you want something to be *printed 5 times*, you include it inside the for loop. May be this will help you.

```
Vx0 = 18
Vy0 = 18
V = 18
Theta = 45
y0 = 1.8    
x0 = 0
p = 1.2 #given density
C = 0.3 #Drag coefficient
dt = 0.2 #Time increment

def x_direction (x0, Vx0, dt):
    """Calculate the distance moved in x axis"""
    new_dist = 0
    for hori_dist in range(5):
        hori_dist = x0 + Vx0*dt
        new_dist = new_dist + hori_dist
        print ("[LOOP] Distance being moved is", hori_dist) #The extra print
        print ("[LOOP] New distance is", new_dist) #Another extra print
    return new_dist

new_dist = x_direction(x0, Vx0, dt)
print ("Distanced moved in x direction is :", new_dist)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put a `print` statement in your loop ,like this

`hori_dist = x0 + Vx0*dt
   print (hori_dist)`

Also, you can't call function like you did here `x_direction(x0, Vx0, dt)`. You should pass values instead of variables `x_direction(0, 18, 0.2)`